# Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

Tags: spring, ejb, applicationcontext, inject

here is the whole expection

> Error creating bean with name 'MyClassBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: interface myInterface to inject 
>   nested exception is myinterface in MyClassBean org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No qualifying bean of type [injected interfacename] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

if you get such as an error that means that you register your injected interface to register in applicationContext.xml file, after registering your interface the exception does not appear.

```
<bean id="nameOfTheInterface" parent="ejbProxy">
                           <property name="jndiName"
                                           value="ejb:ear/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT//InterfaceIpml!interface" />
                           <property name="businessInterface" value="interface" />
            </bean>
```

however in this case you need to register your interface in the aplicationcontext.xml file which you inject

Comment: Is there a question being asked here?

Comment: it is the injected interfacename. would you please edit it and remove the packagename. thx. @jb nizet, i changed it in my code to [injected interfacename]

Comment: @suatCoskun What is your question? I expect to see a sentence ending with a question mark. If you just want to write something about Pring, then write a blog post. Don't ask a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sundararaj Govindasamy please remove the package name in your comment thx.

Comment: @suatCoskun, As I am not able to edit my previous comment, I deleted it